# Vagrant synced_folder overwriting guest folder

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I'm having an issue, where after starting the vagrant box, the synced_folder is erasing all the contents of the target folder on the guest machine (I'm guessing that it's overwriting it).

I have the following line in my Vagrantfile

```
config.vm.synced_folder "folder/", "/home/vagrant/src/folder/"
```

I verified that `/home/vagrant/src/folder` has content, then adding the synced_folder command to Vagrant file causes it to be empty after startup.

I don't know if it's because I'm missing some configuration options, a permissions issue, or what.

I'm on mac OS X 10.9.2 with VirtualBox 4.3.12

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the folder `/home/vagrant/src/folder/` exists inside the guest OS (which is sounds like), any contents there won't be overwritten, but they will be hidden because Vagrant will use that same path as the mount point. If you disable the share, then do a `vagrant reload` and `vagrant ssh`, you'll probably see the old contents reappear.

The sharing is mainly helpful for getting files on the host OS to be visible in the guest OS, not so much the other way around.

One workaround might be to use the normal folder share (into `/vagrant`), then inside the guest OS create a symbolic link to the content you want visible back on the host OS. You could add that to your `.profile` to run it each time you ssh into the guest.

Answer (score 1):

As BrianC mentioned, it is NOT overwriting, but expected behaviour.

Vagrant mounts the `folder` in your project folder to `/home/vagrant/src/folder/` within the guest. As a result, the contents in the original folder will be hidden unless you manually unmount the vagrant share (by default `vboxsf`).

You can change the mount point (within guest) of the share to workaround the issue.

BTW: The default `vboxsf` has its limitations, there are new type of synced fodlers, e.g. rsync, NFS, smb. I personally would recommend using rsync type.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, would you mind explaining how to change the mount point within in the guest to get this to work?

Comment: @CraigKochis Run `findmnt` or `mount`, you'll probably see some `vboxsf` type of file system mounted as `/home/vagrant/src/folder`, you can try to run `umount -l /home/vagrant/src/folder` to unmount it as root.